# How does Google test and check Android apps uploaded to Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

I have found so many apps on the Google Play Store which are just useless. There are so many apps whose names are like "Useless App", "Nothing" and just rubbish, even in their app descriptions, it is written that this app does nothing, and those apps really do nothing. And the irony is that even these apps have hundreds of thousands of downloads.

How does Google test the apps uploaded?

Comment: How do you categorize something as **useless**?? What right does Google Play Store have to remove an app as useless?? If an app does not violate the norms of Play Store, it automatically goes live after security testing. Google doesn't have the right to decide which app is 'useless'; it's the developer's choice. If you don't like an app, you're free to rate it with low stars, and if you find it violating any rules, you may report it.

Comment: By useless, I mean when you install it, it only shows "Useless" on the screen and does nothing. Even its name and description is "Useless", which is provided by the developer by himself.

Comment: And if you want, you can search the term "Useless App" in the play store. Or I can also provide you some examples.

Comment: Good question. In all those years, I've found quite a bit of gibberish on the supposedly "safe" Play Store. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my personal experience, Google does not check each and every functionality of the app, it just does some routine validation check for publication. Whereas Apple's App Store does the opposite, Apple requires working login credentials for checking each and every screen at least.

Now, it is perfectly fine to publish an app in Play Store, which does nothing, i.e., useless till the time it is adhering to the Play Store's policy. Now if you found some apps which are violating the listed policy [Play Store Policy](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/), you can always report it to Google and most probably Google will unlist that app for sure.